# PGF Plots is cutting off part of a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here I have a plot of two functions in latex, the shorter one is listed on the bottom and the taller on the top. This taller function should meet the x axis. Does anyone know how I can get this function to be plotted for its full range?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-2,ymin=0,xmax=2,ymax=2.5,domain=-2:2, restrict y to domain=0:2.1221,samples=250,grid=major,xlabel={\(x\)},ylabel={\(P(x)\)},title={}]
    \addplot[black, thick]{2/(pi * 0.3^2) * (0.3^2 - x^2)^(1/2)};
    \addplot[black, thick]{2/(pi * 2^2) * (2^2 - x^2)^(1/2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```

And a picture of the current result:

[image]

Comment: Why is there **\begin{equation*}**? That does make any sense to me. This was also mentioned in the answer to your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At |x|>0.3 you will get a negative square root, whick gives a complex number. That's the problem in your graph. I suppose that if you put a fixed domain with a fixed number of samples for both graphs in your axes description, an array of equally spaced number of values between -2 and 2 will be created. Since the real domain of your first graph is between -0.3 and 0.3, you will get a graph with a short amount of samples since the square root will give a complex output in most cases.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2,ymin=0,xmax=2,ymax=2.5,
    domain=-2:2,
    restrict y to domain=0:2.1221,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={\(x\)},ylabel={\(P(x)\)},title={}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-0.3:0.3,black, thick]{2/(pi * 0.3^2) * (0.3^2 - x^2)^(1/2)};
    \addplot[black, thick]{2/(pi * 2^2) * (2^2 - x^2)^(1/2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Correct me if I'm wrong and hope it works now!